# How to query _entities in Apollo Router?

Tags: graphql, apollo-federation

While resolving GraphQL request, Apollo Router makes requests that include field `_entities(representations: $representations)` to internal services.

However, when trying to issue the same query to externally available Apollo Router, I get an error

```
parsing error: cannot query field '_entities' on type 'Query'
```

So, internal service resolves `_entities` just fine, however Apollo Router return above error.

Is it possible to get Apollo Router resolve `_entities` without changing anything in Apollo Router?

If not, what can be changed in Apollo Router to resolve `_entities`?